# Heroku Missing Template Error RoR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku

I have been trying to get this app to deploy correctly to Heroku for over a day now and having solved one error after another I am stuck on this one.

I am being served a `We're Sorry something went wrong` 500 error and I have the following log:

```
 2012-10-21T17:40:32+00:00 app[web.1]: [2012-10-21 17:40:32] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
 2012-10-21T17:40:32+00:00 app[web.1]: [2012-10-21 17:40:32] INFO  ruby 1.9.2 (2011-07-09) [x86_64-linux]
 2012-10-21T17:40:32+00:00 app[web.1]: [2012-10-21 17:40:32] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=2 port=18894
 2012-10-21T17:40:33+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
 2012-10-21T17:41:55+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to starting
 2012-10-21T17:41:57+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rails server -p 44537`
 2012-10-21T17:41:58+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
 2012-10-21T17:41:58+00:00 app[web.1]:   /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.rb:90:in `select'
 2012-10-21T17:41:58+00:00 app[web.1]: [2012-10-21 17:41:58] ERROR SignalException: SIGTERM
 2012-10-21T17:41:59+00:00 app[web.1]: => Booting WEBrick
 2012-10-21T17:41:59+00:00 app[web.1]: => Rails 3.2.0 application starting in production on http://0.0.0.0:18894
 2012-10-21T17:41:59+00:00 app[web.1]: => Call with -d to detach
 2012-10-21T17:41:59+00:00 app[web.1]: => Ctrl-C to shutdown server
 2012-10-21T17:41:59+00:00 app[web.1]:
 2012-10-21T17:41:59+00:00 app[web.1]:
 2012-10-21T17:41:59+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/" for 86.9.116.69 at 2012-10-21 17:41:59 +0000
 2012-10-21T17:42:00+00:00 app[web.1]:
 2012-10-21T17:42:00+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionView::MissingTemplate (Missing template /404 with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :coffee, :haml]}. Searched in:
 2012-10-21T17:42:00+00:00 app[web.1]:   * "/app/app/views"
 2012-10-21T17:42:00+00:00 app[web.1]:   * "/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rails_admin-0.1.2/app/views"
 2012-10-21T17:42:00+00:00 app[web.1]:   * "/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/kaminari-0.14.1/app/views"
 2012-10-21T17:42:00+00:00 app[web.1]:   * "/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/devise-2.1.2/app/views"
 2012-10-21T17:42:00+00:00 app[web.1]: ):
 2012-10-21T17:42:00+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/controllers/application_controller.rb:10:in `render_404'
 2012-10-21T17:42:00+00:00 app[web.1]:
 2012-10-21T17:42:00+00:00 app[web.1]:
 2012-10-21T17:42:00+00:00 app[web.1]: cache: [GET /] miss
 2012-10-21T17:42:00+00:00 heroku[router]: GET secure-ocean-9819.herokuapp.com/ dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=340ms status=500 bytes=643
```

Everything works perfectly on Localhost so I am confused why it seems to be struggling on Heroku.

Any help people can offer really would be much appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

You have the method/action - render_404 in Application Controller, which has code to handle 404 issues

```
 2012-10-21T17:42:00+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/controllers/application_controller.rb:10:in `render_404'
```

Can you try to run the application locally in Production mode. In the production mode application loads all classes first and throws exceptions, if any.

If you just want to run to test, you can comment out that action.